# how do i resolve runtime error in this code for creating tree...?

Tags: tree, runtime-error

/* this is a program for creating a tree using structures.

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

/*tree structure
for creating a tree*

```
struct tree{
    int data;                   
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
    };
```

/*function to insert element in tree*/

```
void insert(struct tree *bt,int data)
{
    if(bt==NULL){
        bt=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
        bt->data=data;
        bt->left=NULL;
        bt->right=NULL;
        }
    else if(data<bt->data)
        insert(&(bt->left),data);
    else if(data>bt->data)
        insert(&(bt->right),data);

}
```

/*inserting elements 
calling the function insert.*/

```
void main(){
    struct tree *bt=NULL;
    insert(&bt,1);
    insert(&bt,6);            
    insert(&bt,12);            
    insert(&bt,87);
    inorder(&bt);
}
```

/*in-order traversal*/
//recursive call of function//

```
void inorder(struct tree *root){
    if(root!=NULL){
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d",root->data);          
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because a tree contains a tree, which contains a tree pointer, which contains a tree pointer, and so on...(even if you're not initializing or "allocating" anything, CPP compilers are weird)

Without the error it's giving you, I can't do much.

Comment: can you give me a correct piece of code for this ??

Comment: Try setting the references to "NULL" so the compiler doesn't initialize it. Example: struct tree *left = NULL; I might be able to help a little more if you provide me with the runtime error. The resolve above fixes a stack-overflow error for a bad compiler.